# Does the penalty shoot out goal count as the person goal for a player?

Tags: rules, football, statistics

I just want to know if the goal scored by a player during shoot out is counted as goal scored in the tournament or not.

For example:
the goal scored by Messi will be counted or not to become the highest goal scorer in the Fifa world cup.

Comment: Then how James Rodrigez goal counted in his total tally when he scored his last goal on a penalty kick?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it does not get counted.
For instance, if we look at the goals scored by Messi during FIFA 2014 World cup:
He has a total of 4 goals till now.

1 vs Bosnia and Herzegovina (group stage)

1 vs Iran (group stage)

2 vs Nigeria (group stage)

The [statistics](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/players/player=229397/statistics.html) from FIFA summarize it the best.

Comment: goals scored in the penalty shoot out also dont cout in other statistics. Such a game would give a goal difference of 0 for both teams in all statistics. (so you can win/loose a game by a goal difference of zero)

Comment: To add to this, the shoot-out is *only* used to determine a winnning team when one is needed and does not enter any *official* results or statistics; if this was not the case it wold be unfair in many (more) aspects, for example that the last players are not allowed to shoot once the outcome is clear - even thogh they might still influence the goal difference (and the individual goal stats)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Penalty Shootouts are different from Penaly Kicks.

Penalty Shootouts are played after the full 90 minutes & extra time. Penalty kicks scored here by the player will not be added to his goal tally.

Penalty Kicks are awarded by fouling an opposition player inside your penalty box. The goal scored by the player will be credited to him, because it inside the 90 minute play or the extra time.